# In asp.net dropdownlist some value disabled to select

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [make drop down list item unselectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379125/make-drop-down-list-item-unselectable)

I have an asp.net dropdownlist and would like to make some values disabled to select. We have a list of 10-100 items that will be in the dropdown list. Users need to select an Item to perform a function.

Each item has a Heading that it's sorted on, 10 items under 1 heading (example). and I want to not allow the heading to be selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try for each element you want to diable:

```
  ListItem i = DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(str);
  i.Attributes.Add("style", "color:gray;");
  i.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
```

Comment: Thanks kman  :) 
You save my time

Answer (score 2):

As long as your DropDownList is populated with items you can easily enable and disable them using the following property:

```
DropDownList1.Items[1].Enabled = false;
DropDownList1.Items[2].Enabled = true;
```

This will lead to the rendering them in HTML as non-selectable.