# How to make an asp dropdown list item unselectable

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have written following code to display drop down list :

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="True" ID="ddlCities" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" TabIndex="5">
       <asp:ListItem>Select City</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem value="3">Ahmedabad (All) ---------------</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem value="3_3004">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ahmedabad East</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem value="3_3005">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ahmedabad West</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem value="3_3006">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ahmedabad-Bopal and Surroundings</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem value="3_3007">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ahmedabad-Gandhinagar</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem value="3_3008">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ahmedabad-Sabarmati and Surroundings</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem value="3_3009">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ahmedabad-SG Highway and Surroundings</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to make following item inside dropdown unselectable :

```
<asp:ListItem value="3">Ahmedabad (All) ---------------</asp:ListItem>
```

Note : I CAN'T USE OPTGROUP!!!!

and i don't want to hide it. it will be shown in dropdown, but user can't select this item.

I have tried adding 'disabled' attribute, but it hides that item.

i have also tried :

```
ddlCities.Items[1].Attributes.Add("Style", "cursor:not-allowed");
```

It doesn't allow cursor, but still user can select this item, is there any other way to make this particular item unselectable??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make drop down list item unselectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379125/make-drop-down-list-item-unselectable)

Comment: @AzarShaikh the solution said in the link won't work, it will hide the item

Answer (score 4):

Even though you said that disabled attribute hides the element, you are wrong. 
Disabled attribute is exactly what you should use for this:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">First</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" disabled="disabled">Second</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">First</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i have already mentioned that disabled attribute will hide that field. what you have shown as RESULT, is what exactly i want, but    <asp:ListItem Value="2" disabled="disabled">Second</asp:ListItem> will hide that item

Comment: @ace I just tested that and it does not hide it. Do you have some javascript or maybe css that hides it? Asp.net does not hide it, it will just disable it.

Comment: i don't have any javascript or css that hides it, but i have    ddlCities.Items[1].Attributes.Add("Style", "cursor:not-allowed"); this in c# code behind file

Comment: can you please share the code snippet which works for you?

Comment: Moreover you can't use disabled="disabled", you can use enabled="true"

Comment: @ace This ***is*** the code that works :) There is no more, as I said asp.net ***does not*** hide the rendered option-element because if has disabled-attribute. It would not even make any sense. And yes you can use disabled="disabled"...

Comment: when i tried disable attribute, it hides that list option. IS it possible for you to show demo, something like jsDiddle

Comment: Then you must have something in your css or javascript that ***hides*** disabled options-elements. I urge you to check your css for option[disabled] or similar... See here https://jsfiddle.net/10u8s05c/1/

Comment: what if i use the same javascript function from  jsfiddle.net/10u8s05c/1    and say display : block ????

Comment: @ace So you found some css that hides the disabled-elements? Then yes you can override the css for this select-element by using a different display-property for it's disabled select-elements. See here https://jsfiddle.net/10u8s05c/2/

Comment: No there isn't any css or javascript which controls the dropdown

Comment: @ace So go and debug and find out why your application hides the disabled option-elements. As you can see from the fiddle, html/browser does not do it, nor does asp.net. With this limited information in your question we can't help you more.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for something like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15505/ASP-NET-DropDownList-with-OptionGroup-support). Please see if it can help you.

**[Update]**
just looked back to your post and understand you cannot use OPTGROUP. May i know the reason? as your requirement needs this option.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. If the link dies, your answer becomes useless.

Comment: @NareshPodishetty i have already tried the solution in the said link, it doesn't works at all