# Disable DropDownList Based On Previous DropDownList Selection

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I having two ASP.Net drop down list with same values inside which are populated from the database according to different data entered by the user and having dynamic size every time. My scenario is that I wish to disable any option on the second drop down list that is already selected on the first drop down list. I did some Google and most results are on `<select></select>` and not the ASP.Net drop down list which is `<asp:DropDownList></asp:DropDownList>`

I have try on following java script and using `<select></select>` but it is not working either.

```
<script>
    $('select').on('change', function () {

        $('select').find('option').prop('disabled', false);

        $('select').each(function () {
            $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Button Code

```
protected void AddStudentSubjectB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnRowDataBoundSubject();
    if(StudentSubjectDDL.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        AddStudentSubjectB.Enabled = false;
        StudentSubjectDDL.Visible = true;
        EnrollStudentSubjectB.Visible = true;
        CancelEnrollStudentSubjectB.Visible = true;
        AddStudentSubjectB1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Drop Down List Populate Code

```
private void OnRowDataBoundSubject()
{
    StudentSubjectDDL.DataSource = GetData("SELECT SUB.ID, SUB.NAME FROM SUBJECT SUB LEFT JOIN RESULT RES ON RES.SUBJECT = SUB.ID WHERE RES.SUBJECT IS NULL OR RES.ID != '" + StudentID1.Text.Trim() + "' AND SUB.COURSE = '" + StudentCourse1.Text.Trim() + "';");
    StudentSubjectDDL.DataTextField = "NAME";
    StudentSubjectDDL.DataValueField = "ID";
    StudentSubjectDDL.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of scope.

When you use "this" in the line:

```
$('select').each(function () {
    $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

You're actually refering to the select itself and not the outer select, so you need to save the outer select in a variable like this:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var outer = this;
    $('select').find('option').prop('disabled', false);

    $('select').each(function () {
        $('select').not(outer).find('option[value="' + outer.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nbvsd28z/1/

**EDIT:**

I have made this fiddle where the options are disabled when the dropdowns are added dynamically: https://jsfiddle.net/m6wxg8x0/2/

Comment: Hi. @Nekura So sorry to say but the code is not working. [Testing](https://i.imgur.com/45CiBnC.gif)

Comment: Hi @TanYihWei,
It looks like the dropdowns are added dynamically by pressing a button, if that's the case the above code won't work, because you can't disable an option that doesn't exist yet.
Could you update your question with this information and add code showing how the dropdowns are added?

Comment: Hi. @Nekura I have updated the question. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @TanYihWei I think it might be better to solve this in backend instead of javascript. After you databind the new dropdownlist, find the selected values from the previous dropdown and disable that value in the new one.
You can see here how you disable an option in backend: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2185923/5908198