# Grey Out Certain Items C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownlistfor, disable

I would like to disable certain members of an `ItemList`. I have tried variations on the following code, but nothing seems to work. I wish to have the disabled `Items` remain in the `list`, but be grey'ed out. I have seem similar posts on this subject, but nothing seems to work.

```
List<SelectListItem> selectitem = new List<SelectListItem>();

selectitem.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "-1", Disabled = false });

while (reader.Read())
{
string displayText = "TextTest";
string displayValue = "ValueTest";

selectitem.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = displayText, Value = displayValue, Disabled = true });
}

EstimateDropDownList.DataSource = selectitem;
EstimateDropDownList.DataTextField = "Text";
EstimateDropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
EstimateDropDownList.DataBind();
```

...

```
  internal class SelectListItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    }
```

...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="EstimateDropDownList" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="27px"
    AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EstimateDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I also tried this, but this did not work either.

```
EstimateDropDownList.DataSource = selectitem;

foreach (ListItem item in EstimateDropDownList.Items)
   {
     if (true)
      {
          item.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
      }
   }

EstimateDropDownList.DataTextField = "Text";
EstimateDropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
EstimateDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make drop down list item unselectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379125/make-drop-down-list-item-unselectable)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is one of the variations I tried. I edited my post to show how I attempted to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Dropdowns are "select" controls with "option" elements. In most browers you can only disable (or color) the control itself and not specific "options". In the past this was a bit different. 
If you DO want to do this, there are many ready JS Dropdown controls or even bootstrap that can do this in a very nice way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It sounds like you are saying this can't be done with: asp:DropDownList from the toolbox? Can you be more specific on controls that can do this? I am new to asp.

Comment: asp:DropDownList is a asp.net control that will eventually create the html select control, so you are still limitted to the limitations of the select control. You basically only have control over the value and the text in each option. Of course you can easily add functionality in the onchange event.

Comment: Take a look at some of these, to give you an idea what you can do with js plugins http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-option or https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/Best-Multiple-Select-jQuery-Plugins.html  or http://www.bestjquery.com/demo/jquery-multiselect-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was wrong. There IS an option to disable a specific select option item in HTML. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

See this dropdown for example:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" disabled>Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

To utilize this:

```
ListItemCollection lic = new ListItemCollection();
lic.Add(new ListItem("first", "1"));
lic.Add(new ListItem("second", "2", false));
lic.Add(new ListItem("third", "3"));

foreach(ListItem li in lic)
{
    //create a new list item, because otherwise it will skip disabled items.
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(li.Text, li.Value));
    if(li.Enabled == false)
    {
        ddl.Items[ddl.Items.Count - 1].Attributes.Add("disabled", "");
    }
}
```

This is rather an odd work-around, since the asp.net control should have known how to generate the disabled property to begin with. I don't know why it is like this, but there is probably a valid reason for that. I would definitely do this differently, either by playing with the text, checking in the post-back, or just leaving out the disabled options. Apparently, it wasn't meant to be like this.