# Disable asp.net dropdownlist specific Iitems

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdownlist with few items which bind in code behind. I populate dropdownlist from below query.

`Select ID, Name, IsGroup from TempTable`

i set DataTextField = "Name" and DataValueField = "ID"

Now i want to disable some items based on "IsGroup" value in DataBound event. How can i access this "IsGroup" column.

```
For Each item As ListItem In dd.Items
      If (What i will compare here = "N") Then
           item.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled")
      End If
Next
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data = GetData();

        List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            var item = new ListItem()
            {
                Value = row["Id"].ToString(),
                Text = row["Name"].ToString()
            };
            if (row["IsGroup"].ToString() != "N")
            {
                item.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
            }

            items.Add(item);
        }
        this.DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
    }
```

ref: [make drop down list item unselectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379125/make-drop-down-list-item-unselectable)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing 2 activities

- Fetching data from the database
- populating the list item and attaching property/properties to the list item element

### Method 1 : Primarily to understand the different operations involved.

```
class SurroundingClass
{
    class Example1
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string IsGroup { get; set; }
    }
    public void PopulateExample1()
    {
        // Separate Sections for Database and Dropdown Manipulation

        // Database operation
        var cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CS").ConnectionString;
        string sql = "Select ID, Name, IsGroup from TempTable";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<Example1> e1 = new List<Example1>();
        while (dr.Read)
        {
            var e = new Example1();
            e.ID = dr.GetInt32(0);
            e.Name = dr.GetString(1);
            e.IsGroup = dr.GetString(2);
            e1.Add(e);
        }
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();

        // Populate Dropdown 
        foreach (var i in e1)
        {
            var li = new ListItem(i.Name, i.ID);
            if (i.IsGroup == "Y")
                li.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
            ddlExample1.Items.Add(li);
        }
    }
}
```

### Method 2 : Squeezing the operations in Method 1 together

```
public void PopulateExample2()
{
    // Database Operation and Dropdown Manipulation together
    var cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CS").ConnectionString;
    string sql = "Select ID, Name, IsGroup from TempTable";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read)
    {
        var li = new ListItem(dr.GetString(1), dr.GetInt32(0));
        if (dr.GetString(2) == "Y")
            li.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
        ddlExample2.Items.Add(li);
    }
    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Please note that there can be several variations to the solution, this being only one of them.