# asp.net and c# disable previous month in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

i want to disable the previous months on the dropdownlist in c#, only when the month is the current month.

for example if i today is september 2020, i want to disable the ability to select from January to August 2020, and i want it to be able to select from september / october / november / december 2020.

[image]

Please help me with this

Here is the code I used at the backend:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack )
        {
            DD_Monthbind();
        }
    }

    private void DD_Monthbind()
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);
        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
        {       
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(info.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));       

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about just not adding in those months that are invalid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make drop down list item unselectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379125/make-drop-down-list-item-unselectable)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb okay ...

Comment: You talk about it being the "current" month, but the dropdown only shows months. How do you know what year is selected?

Comment: @ADyson the year selected is always the current year

Comment: ok well just look at DateTime.Now, get the current month from that, and then use an `if` statement to decide whether the month you're about to add to the dropdown list comes before that month or not. If it's before it, then just don't add it to the list, so it can never even be seen, never mind selected. No need to disable anything - just don't put it there in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have hinted in the comments, it is usually better (at least from a usability standpoint) to omit unneeded drop-down values instead of disabling them:

```
private void DD_Monthbind()
{
    DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);
    int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;

    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        bool isMonthInPast = i < currentMonth;

        if (!isMonthInPast)
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(info.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));       
    }
}
```

If you really want to disable the values, you can use JavaScript or CSS to do it.  For example (this is jQuery):

```
$(/* drop-down value selector */).prop('disabled', true);
```